# Trying to recreate Tom Riddle's Text Effect with Webkit Animation CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to recreate Tom Riddle's text animation from Harry Potter chambers of secrets (as seen on [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh4b5zC0sB4)). I currently am still trying to use css in simulating it as can be done on Adobe Ae (as seen on [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH76LxUhY88&t)). Currently, what I have done is using keyframes to simulate the fade in a loop. I have no idea on how to move forward in this process. Here is my current code:

```css
body{
    background-color: bisque;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100px;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 550px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -150px; 
}

.tr-fade{
    opacity: 0; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-name: tr-fade-animation;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: forward;
}

@keyframes tr-fade-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="text-container">
            <div class="center tr-fade">
                Hi, This is Tom Riddle.
            </div>     
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have researched about fractal noises in css, however none seemed to use image masking for text transition effects. What approach should I use in order to get the desired effect (SVG animation maybe)? Any help on this?

Comment: Maybe you could use [knockout text](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) and either animate the background image or animate an SVG fill.

Comment: How do I approach this exactly? As far as I understand, I have to make a video for SVG full with knockout text. Is this the case? If so, that means it is not going to be an animation but a unversatile effect instead? @TrevinAvery

Comment: You don't need to make a video for SVG. You can create an SVG using text, and set the background/fill to some shape that is all black. Then you can create an animation that alters that shape, creating the fading effect. Maybe it will be many shapes, or some random pattern. Not sure exactly.